# Struggling to understand jquery - Fade in/out a class on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, fade

I'm currently trying to learn jQuery and JavaScript, and for my navigation I'm trying to make it look underlined on mouseover which, although it might not be the cleaned of code, I have managed to do it using a addClass and removeClass.

I am now trying to make the underline class fade in and fade out, which I believe is something normally done with CSS3 but due to just trying to learn jquery, I've been trying to figure it out.

I've tried putting .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() in different places in the code, but nothing seems to work, so I'm assuming this is not the correct way to do it.

**Here's my code**

**HTML**

```
   <div class="navleft">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">Home</li>
            <li class="active1">Dealerships</li>
            <li class="active1">Contact</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .navleft ul li.active1 {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #999;
    border-style: solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

   .navleft ul li.active {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #999;
    border-style: solid;
    cursor: pointer;

    }
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(function(){
    $('.navleft ul li').removeClass('active1');


    $('.navleft ul li').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active1');
    });

    $('.navleft ul li').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active1');
    })

    });
```

If anyone could help, that would be great, as I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: First, your `.active1` and `.active` classes are the same.  Second, the border declaration could be rewritten as `.border-bottom: 1px solid #999`.  Third, it seems that you are interested in animating change from one border appearance to another.  The latter can be done using jQuery, but as others have said, it is better to do it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can't fade in or out. `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are for the opacity of elements. If you actually want to ›fade‹ a style you have to either write your own animation code (which I wouldn't recommend) or use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), which I would recommend anyways.

Comment: well, in a way, they can if you have jQuery UI installed. css transitions though would be smoother, more efficient, lighter, etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS way to smoothly transition from one border to another on hovering: http://jsfiddle.net/u4h7k/2/.

HTML:

```
<ul id = "nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Dealerships</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav > li {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav > li:before, #nav > li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

#nav > li:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    opacity: 1;
}

#nav > li:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav > li:hover:before {
    opacity: 1; 
}
```